# Temporary variables in Mathematica

Tags: python, oop, wolfram-mathematica

I have written a package for Mathematica called MathOO. In short, it allows you to use object orientation in Mathematica just like you do in Python. Please read the following article in [Voofie/MathOO](http://voofie.com/concept/MathOO/) for details:

[MathOO: Adding Python style Object Orientation to Mathematica with MathOO (1.0 beta launch) [Alternative to Objectica]](http://voofie.com/content/169/mathoo-adding-python-style-object-orientation-to-mathematica-with-mathoo-10-beta-launch-alternative-/)

The problem I encountered is that, I would like to have garbage collector, so that user don't have to explicitly deleting the object after using it. For instance:

```
NewClass[Object1]
Object1.$init$[self_]:= Return[];
```

In the above two lines, I just defined Object1 to be a new class, and the constructor to be an empty function. If you are familiar with Python, you should see the similarity with `__init__()`.

To instantiate an Object1, I do:

```
object1 = new[Object1][]
```

The output is:

```
Out: object$13
```

Here, object$13 is an temporary variable. What I want is, when there are no references to this temporary variable, it should be deleted automatically. But it doesn't work as expected. I have identified the problem to be the following:

```
In:  y = Module[{x}, x[1] = 2; x]
Out: x$117

In:  FullDefinition[y]
Out: y = x$117
     Attributes[x$117] = {Temporary}
     x$117[1] = 2
```

Since y holds a reference of x$117, so x$117 is not removed yet. Now let's delete the reference by setting the value of y to 1:

```
In:  y = 1;
```

However, x$117 is still here:

```
In:  Definition[x$117]
Out: Attributes[x$117] = {Temporary}
     x$117[1] = 2
```

But I expected the variable to be removed since it is no longer referenced. From the [manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Temporary.html) of Mathematica, it said:

> Temporary symbols are removed if they are no longer referenced:

So, is it a bug of Mathematica? Or is there any workaround methods? I am using Mathematica 7.0. Thank you very much.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867892/reducing-memory-usage-in-an-extended-mathematica-session/6873142#6873142) for some bugs in the garbage collector related to `Module`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica really does garbage collects `Temporary` variables when they have no more references. That said, there's two reasons that your x$117 is not garbage collected.

1. Remember that `Module` uses lexical scoping, so the module variables are only "local" in the sense that they are give a unique name "var$modnum" and the `Temporary` `Attribute`.
   Since you gave your `x` a `DownValue`, it must be cleared before `x` can be garbage collected.
2. Your `y` was set to be the temporary variable `x$...` and the output was assigned to `Out[]`. So you also need to clear the history: `Unprotect[In, Out]; Clear[In, Out]; Protect[In, Out];`.

Then your `Module` example seems to be properly garbage collected.

---

When using your MathOO package (that I downloaded yesterday, but haven't played with yet) maybe you can just set the `$HistoryLength` to some finite number. <strike>And recommend that users suppress the output of instantiations `object1 = new[Object1][];`</strike>

Comment: Yes. For the 2nd point, I normally would suppress the output. I omitted the ; just for the program to output the variable name so that I can see its definition later. Now, the main problem is that, I don't know when the user will make no references, and DownValue is a must. Is that DownValue is another reference that's outside the scope of x? I just don't wanted to clear the DownValue, and hope that it can still be garbage collected.

Comment: I would like to use the variable as a dictionary. Like dict in Python. When there is no reference to the variable, the DownValue has no meaning at all, and so should be garbage collected. I don't understand why Mathematica doesn't collect it and thinks I still wanna use it afterwards.

Comment: Note that suppressing output with `;` does not prevent the assignment of the actual return value to `Out[n]`.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for reminding us of that - both my answer and i-freaker's comment made that wrong assumption.

Comment: @i-freaker: I understand exactly what you want (and can guess how it fits into MathOO, despite your `Encode`ing of the package :( ). I'm not sure if can be simply implemented but maybe your Q on mathgroup will get answered by someone from WRI.  I'm not sure if WRI would consider the Module/Temporary behaviour as a bug or a feature! I can think of a couple of ugly hacks, but nothing that would be fast and convenient...

Comment: I think of a hack too. But will added quite a bit complexity to the simple code. Also, I can't do garbage collection in a regular time interval. I can't find any Timer function to execute a function in a particular time, or when the memory is low.

Comment: @i-freaker: how about making a palette (that can be disabled) that opens up when your package is loaded (like http://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/) it has a dynamically updated list of classes and objects. And another dynamically updated object that tracks memory usage, which has a garbage control mechanism built in with a large `UpdateInterval`?

Comment: Thank you Simon for your idea. I think stack overflow isn't good for discussion. Please join the discussion in this post. http://voofie.com/content/178/adding-garbage-collector-to-mathoo/. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: @Ross In Mma8 there is now the function http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CreateScheduledTask.html

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica is a string rewriting system (at the bottom) (sort of) (not really) (but really) (ANYWAY...)  The DownValue "x$117[1] = 2" is a string rewriting rule that it is not entirely inaccurate to imagine is an entry in an associative array.  The array is named "x$117" and the entry is the pair {1,2}.  As long as there is an entry in the array, the symbol "x$117" is referenced and will not be GCed by Mma.

Your best bet is to Remove[] symbols when they are destructed or go out of scope.  (Clear[] is insufficient since lingering attributes, messages, or defaults associated with symbols are not eliminated by Clear[] and so Mma will still hold live references to the symbol.)