# Reducing memory usage in an extended Mathematica session

Tags: memory-leaks, wolfram-mathematica, memory-management

I'm doing some rather long computations, which can easily span a few days. In the course of these computations, sometimes Mathematica will run out of memory. To this end, I've ended up resorting to something along the lines of:

```
ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID]; (* Force the kernels to launch *)
kernels = Kernels[];

Do[
   If[Mod[iteration, n] == 0,
      CloseKernels[kernels];
      LaunchKernels[kernels];
      ClearSystemCache[]];
   (* Complicated stuff here *)
   Export[...], (* If a computation ends early I don't want to lose past results *)
   {iteration, min, max}]
```

This is great and all, but over time the main kernel accumulates memory. Currently, my main kernel is eating up roughly 1.4 GB of RAM. Is there any way I can force Mathematica to clear out the memory it's using? I've tried littering `Share` and `Clear` throughout the many `Modules` I'm using in my code, but the memory still seems to build up over time.

I've tried also to make sure I have nothing big and complicated running outside of a `Module`, so that something doesn't stay in scope too long. But even with this I still have my memory issues.

Is there anything I can do about this? I'm always going to have a large amount of memory being used, since most of my calculations involve several large and dense matrices (usually 1200 x 1200, but it can be more), so I'm wary about using `MemoryConstrained`.

---

**Update:**

The problem was exactly what Alexey Popkov stated in his answer. If you use `Module`, memory will leak slowly over time. It happened to be exacerbated in this case because I had multiple `Module[..]` statements. The "main" `Module` was within a `ParallelTable` where 8 kernels were running at once. Tack on the (relatively) large number of iterations, and this was a breeding ground for **lots** of memory leaks due to the bug with `Module`.

Comment: I'd first make sure that you are not leaking memory by some of your code. Typical memory - leaking scenarios include `Module` variables to which you assign some `DownValues` inside `Module`, or which you return from the  `Module`(since those won't be garbage-collected), results accumulated in `In` and `Out`, and system cache. Generally, I'd make an effort to better identify the reason for memory accumulation, perhaps by simulating some parts of what you do in a simplified way.

Comment: @Leonid Could you please give an example when `Module` variables are not removed due to results accumulated in system cache?

Comment: @Alexey You probably misinterpreted my statement: I mentioned 3 different causes - `Module` variables with `DownValues`, `In`-`Out`, *and* system cache. I did not state that any of these necessarily affect one another.

Comment: @Leonid As on `In` - `Out` it is certainly true that it can cause non-deletion `Module` variables, for example execute `Module[{a}, a]` in one cell and then ``Names["`*"]`` in another. I just have not heard so far that the same effect may appear due to internal caching mechanism. Is it your hypothesis?

Comment: @Alexey No, as I said, I did not mean that. For `Module` variables, I meant cases like `Module[{x}, x[a_, b_] := a + b; f[a_] := x[a, 1]]`, where `x` is referenced by an external symbol (`f` here). The problem is that even after we `Clear` `f`, this `Module`-generated `x` and its definitions remain. Some of the things that can be such an external reference are `In` and `Out`, no question about it. Whether or not system cache can also be causing this, I don't know.

Comment: I'll see if I can get find ways to find where memory is leaking, but I have about 7 large code blocks to deal with. One thing that probably doesn't help at all is the fact that I'm running a parallel computation with 8 kernels. But any single iteration of my computation never eats up more than ~400 MB of memory per kernel (I have 12 GB total on this particular machine). This only gets to be an issue over long time scales.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are using `Module` extensively, I think you may be interested in knowing [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/b599b45b9c312e97/3aece5f132c2de27) bug with non-deleting temporary `Module` variables.

Example (non-deleting unlinked temporary variables with their definitions):

```
In[1]:= $HistoryLength=0;
a[b_]:=Module[{c,d},d:=9;d/;b===1];
Length@Names[$Context<>"*"]

Out[3]= 6

In[4]:= lst=Table[a[1],{1000}];
Length@Names[$Context<>"*"]

Out[5]= 1007

In[6]:= lst=.
Length@Names[$Context<>"*"]

Out[7]= 1007

In[8]:= Definition@d$999

Out[8]= Attributes[d$999]={Temporary}

d$999:=9
```

Note that in the above code I set `$HistoryLength = 0;` to stress this buggy behavior of `Module`. If you do not do this, temporary variables can still be linked from history variables (`In` and `Out`) and will not be removed with their definitions due to this reason in more broad set of cases (it is not a bug but a feature, as Leonid mentioned).

**UPDATE:** Just for the record. There is another old [bug with non-deleting unreferenced `Module` variables after `Part` assignments to them](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/f95a9588b9803f54) in v.5.2 which is not completely fixed even in version 7.0.1:

```
In[1]:= $HistoryLength=0;$Version
Module[{L=Array[0&,10^7]},L[[#]]++&/@Range[100];];
Names["L$*"]
ByteCount@Symbol@#&/@Names["L$*"]
Out[1]= 7.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (February 18, 2009)
Out[3]= {L$111}
Out[4]= {40000084}
```

Comment: If I change the definition to `a[b_] := Module[{c, d}, c := 1; d := 9;];`, this still "works", leaving lots of `d$` symbols bound. But no `c$` symbols are left. Why is that?

Comment: @acl I do not see your definition "working" with version 7.0.1 for Windows. Have you restarted the kernel before checking?

Comment: hm, yes, but somehow I was executing your definition again, not the one I thought I was... In any case thanks for the link, I had missed it in the mathgroup.

Comment: This seemed to be the exact issue I was running into. It's unfortunate that this bug is still hanging around. I hope the guys at Wolfram fix this in the next version.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to evaluate `$HistoryLength=0;` in all subkernels and as well as in the master kernel? History tracking is the most common source for going out of memory.

Have you tried do not use slow and memory-consuming `Export` and use fast and efficient `Put` instead?

It is not clear from your post where you evaluate `ClearSystemCache[]` - in the master kernel or in subkernels? It looks like you evaluate it in the master kernel only. Try to evaluate it in all subkernels too before each iteration.